# Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch?

Tags: ios, uikit

I am working on a table view application and I got this type of run time error:

> Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Any suggestion and sample codes are expected.

Answer (score 6):

The warning means that in your application delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method you should assign a view controller as the main window's `rootViewController`:

```
self.window.rootViewController = myRootViewController;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the standard implementation from a Single View Application. Note that a View Controller is allocated and initialised and then assigned to self.window.rootViewController

Your application would have had something like this but somehow you have lost/deleted the self.sindow.rootViewController assignment

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```